# How can I get Items from a Listview items which has both String(Name) and Integer(Contacts)?

Tags: android

I was trying to retrieve the values from ListView items as " mylistview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()" but its returning only the position of the item I am clicking.

**My MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    RelativeLayout rl1;
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0,bhash,bStar,del,call;
    EditText editText;
    Intent phoneIntent,callIntent;
    getContacts.MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ListView lv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        rl1=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        rl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        b9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
        b0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
        bhash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHash);
        bStar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStar);
        call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
        del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDel);

        getContacts.getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
    myAdapter = new getContacts.MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());

         final List<Object> name2 = new ArrayList<>();
        final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                rl1.setVisibility(rl1.isShown()?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"1" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"2"+str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);

                    }
                });
                b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"3" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"4" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"5" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"6" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"7" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"8" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"9" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                b0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"0" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                bhash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"#" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                bStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String str = editText.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = (String) str.substring(0, pos);
                        String str2 = (String) str.substring(pos);
                        editText.setText(str1+"*" +str2);
                        int pos1 = pos+1;
                        editText.setSelection(pos1);
                    }
                });
                call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String number = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (number.charAt(0)!='*') {
                            if (number.length()<=9)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                                startActivity(phoneIntent);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (number.subSequence(number.length()-1,number.length()).equals("#"))
                        {
                            number = number.substring(0, number.length() - 1);
                            String callInfo = "tel:" + number + Uri.encode("#");
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(callInfo));
                            startActivity(callIntent);
                        }
                    }
                });
                del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int posElse =  editText.getSelectionStart();
                        String text = editText.getText().toString();
                        if(text.length()!=0 && posElse >= 1) {
                            int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                            String str1 = (String) text.substring(0, pos-1);
                            if(str1.equals(null))
                            {

                            }
                            String str2 = (String) text.substring(pos);
                            String latest = str1+str2;
                            editText.setText(latest);
                            int pos1 = pos-1;
                            editText.setSelection(pos1);
                        }
                        else if ( posElse < 1)
                        {
                            int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();

                            String str2 = (String) text.substring(pos);
                            String latest = str2;
                            editText.setText(latest);
                            int pos1 = pos;
                            editText.setSelection(pos1);
                        }
                    }
                });

                del.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        if (del.equals(v))
                        {
                            editText.setText("");
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

**My getContacts.java:**

```
public class getContacts {
    static List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        MyAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            //mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             tv.setText(name1.get(position));
           // tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));


            return vi;
        }

    }

}
```

Can somebody please help me out to get the data from the selected list item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try make methods in your adapter, something like this:

```
public String getName(int position) {
    return name1.get(position);
}

public String getPhoneNumber(int position) {
    return phno1.get(position);
}
```

Since you say you got the index, call these methods in your mainactivity on your adapter object. This only works if the positions of the items in your arraylist matches.

I also suggest to use objects to store your data, look here for more info: https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial